# Building and using pnacl-compiler-rt with coverage functionality included

Tags: c++, linker-errors, google-nativeclient

I'm currently having some serious trouble with making use of pnacl-compiler-rt, as I've had no success in finding any info on getting it to build (on Mac, which may or may not be relevant in the case of NaCl) with the instrumentation stuff (e.g. to include GCDAProfiling). My most recent attempt was to modify `make/options.mk`:

```
#Added this
FUNCTIONS := GCDAProfiling
```

I checked the library to see whether it was in there using `ar -t libcompiler_rt.a`:

```
__.SYMDEF SORTED
GCDAProfiling.o  ------------- Here it is
clzti2.o
compilerrt_fmax.o
compilerrt_fmaxf.o
compilerrt_logb.o
compilerrt_logbf.o
ctzti2.o
divdc3.o
divdi3.o
divmoddi4.o
divmodsi4.o
divsc3.o
divsi3.o
divti3.o
fixdfdi.o
fixdfsi.o
fixdfti.o
fixsfdi.o
fixsfsi.o
fixsfti.o
fixunsdfdi.o
fixunsdfsi.o
fixunsdfti.o
fixunssfdi.o
fixunssfsi.o
fixunssfti.o
floatdidf.o
floatdisf.o
floatsidf.o
floatsisf.o
floattidf.o
floattisf.o
floatundidf.o
floatundisf.o
floatunsidf.o
floatunsisf.o
floatuntidf.o
floatuntisf.o
int_util.o
moddi3.o
modsi3.o
modti3.o
muldc3.o
muloti4.o
mulsc3.o
multi3.o
popcountdi2.o
popcountsi2.o
popcountti2.o
powidf2.o
powisf2.o
udivdi3.o
udivmoddi4.o
udivmodsi4.o
udivmodti4.o
udivsi3.o
udivti3.o
umoddi3.o
umodsi3.o
umodti3.o
```

I've copied this library into the `pepper_49/lib/clang-newlib_x86_64/[Debug|Release]` folders.

I've also updated the pepper_49 `earth` example's Makefile in order to attempt to get some code coverage data, changing only the following lines:

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := clang-newlib
...
LIBS = ppapi_simple_cpp nacl_io sdk_util ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread compiler_rt
...
CFLAGS = --coverage -Wall
```

When I attempt to build, I get the following (please note that I have also attempted 64-bit linking but attached the wrong output, with no current means to replace it with the correct output...):

```
  CXX  clang-newlib/Release/earth_x86_32.o
  LINK clang-newlib/Release/earth_unstripped_x86_32.nexe
clang-newlib/Release/earth_x86_32.o: In function `__llvm_gcov_writeout':
earth.cc:(.text+0xb53c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_start_file'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb57c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb59c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb5dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb5fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb63c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb65c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb69c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb6bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb6fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb71c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb75c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb77c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb7bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb7dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb81c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb83c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb87c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb89c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb8dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb8fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb93c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb95c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb99c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb9bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xb9fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xba1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xba5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xba7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbabc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbadc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbb1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbb3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbb7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbb9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbbdc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbbfc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbc3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbc5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbc9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbcbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbcfc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbd1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbd5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbd7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbdbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbddc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbe1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbe3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbe7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbe9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbedc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbefc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbf3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbf5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbf9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbfbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xbffc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc01c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc05c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc07c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc0bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc0dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc11c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc13c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc17c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc19c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc1dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc1fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc23c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc25c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc29c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc2bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc2fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc31c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc35c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc37c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc3bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc3dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc41c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc43c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc47c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc49c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc4dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc4fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc53c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc55c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc59c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc5bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc5fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc61c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc65c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc67c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc6bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc6dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc71c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc73c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc77c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc79c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc7dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc7fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc83c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc85c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc89c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc8bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc8fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc91c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc95c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc97c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc9bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xc9dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xca1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xca3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xca7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xca9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcadc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcafc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcb3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcb5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcb9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcbbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcbfc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcc1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcc5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcc7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xccbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xccdc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcd1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcd3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcd7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcd9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcddc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcdfc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xce3c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xce5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xce9c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcebc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcefc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcf1c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcf5c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcf7c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcfbc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xcfdc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd01c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd03c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd07c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd09c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd0dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd0fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd13c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd15c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd19c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd1bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd1fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd21c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd25c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd27c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd2bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd2dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd31c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd33c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd37c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd39c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd3dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd3fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd43c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd45c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd49c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd4bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd4fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd51c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd55c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd57c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd5bc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_function'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd5dc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_emit_arcs'
earth.cc:(.text+0xd5fc): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_summary_info'
clang-newlib/Release/earth_x86_32.o: In function `__llvm_gcov_init':
earth.cc:(.text+0x1127c): undefined reference to `llvm_gcov_init'
clang-newlib/Release/earth_x86_32.o: In function `__llvm_gcov_writeout':
earth.cc:(.text+0xd605): undefined reference to `llvm_gcda_end_file'
i686-nacl-clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [clang-newlib/Release/earth_unstripped_x86_32.nexe] Error 1
```

I'm doing something (probably several) incredibly basic wrong here, but without any documentation I'm at a loss as to how to:

1. Build pnacl-compiler-rt correctly
2. Get it to link so that I can instrument my .nexe files and get some coverage data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. To build correctly you need to build with the NaCl toolchain compiler (Assumption, you have only built with you host compiler i.e. Mac)
2. To link, once built with the NaCl toolchain linking should work fine. Although note in your example you have put the library in the 64bit folder and you are trying to build a 32bit example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll double check the compiler used, which I may well be the wrong one, as I've not touched the majority of the make files. Re point 2: That's less of an issue, I also attemped 64-bit linking (make NACL_ARCH=x86_64) but attached the wrong output :-/ I'd correct it but won't be near that PC for a week.